# Android - How do I find what is causing StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, multithreading, exception

I have an app that opens up a webview and, in a different thread (asynctask), periodically submits GPS data over http to the server.

I am seeing the following exception but having a difficult time pinpointing the source. Can you help? Relative newbie to Android here.

```
V/  Exception Handler(  206): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
V/  Exception Handler(  206): 
V/  Exception Handler(  206): --------- Stack trace ---------
V/  Exception Handler(  206): 
V/  Exception Handler(  206):     java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:190)
V/  Exception Handler(  206):     android.webkit.FrameLoader.populateStaticHeaders(FrameLoader.java:372)
V/  Exception Handler(  206):     android.webkit.FrameLoader.handleHTTPLoad(FrameLoader.java:222)
V/  Exception Handler(  206):     android.webkit.WebViewWorker.handleMessage(WebViewWorker.java:129)
V/  Exception Handler(  206):     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
V/  Exception Handler(  206):     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
V/  Exception Handler(  206):     android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

The trace gives no indication of what if anything inside my code is causing this. I see only android system code.(or may be I am not looking the right way).

Comment: Consider using debugger. It's helpful sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Having a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in the String constructor is rare enough that I have not encountered it before. What kind of data are you passing to the AsyncTask (which it subsequently passes to WebKit)? Is it a string buffer or some array?

Usually when I can't deduce the cause of a bug, I try:

- stepping through the code to find out which line causes the crash
- printing debug statements

**EDIT**

When I tried to force a `StringOutOfBoundsException` on my emulator, it was a `FATAL EXCEPTION`, the log level was `Error`, and the log tag was `AndroidRuntime`. In your case, it appears that an `ExceptionHandler` has caught the exception and has printed the stack trace with the `Verbose` log level. Is this exception handler your own? or does it belong to the android framework?

Comment: Jim: You are right. I am using my a default uncaught exception handler, set using  Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyExceptionHandler(this));

Comment: In that case, are you able to print the message in the StringIndexOutOfBoundsException? Usually this exception tells you which index it is trying to access when it goes out of bounds. Might be enlightening.